# How to convert list of hex values into a byte array in python

Tags: python, arrays

i have hex list like this 
['0x1', '0x3', '0x2', '0x0', '0x0', '0x10', '0x4', '0x0', '0x0', '0xfa', '0x4']

and i intend to send it over USB, so i need to convert into a bytearray, is there a way available in python?

Comment: @downvoter: It's a valid question, why the downvote?

Comment: I did't down vote :), May be because of lack of research to ask this question.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question, because he has leading '0x'

Comment: true i have this extra 0x which i am trying to convert to bytes, i tried doing a int conversion and then to bytes, but the solution from @koalo is perfect, marking it as best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be solved by a simple one line expression

```
input = ['0x1', '0x3', '0x2', '0x0', '0x0', '0x10', '0x4', '0x0', '0x0', '0xfa', '0x4']
result = bytes([int(x,0) for x in input])
```

The result is

```
b'\x01\x03\x02\x00\x00\x10\x04\x00\x00\xfa\x04'
```

If you do not actually want to have a byte array, but an array of integers, just remove the `bytes()`

```
result = [int(x,0) for x in input]
```

The result is

```
[1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 16, 4, 0, 0, 250, 4]
```

Comment: thanks @koalo for your response, one small correction is to use bytearray instead of bytes , i am not sure if its due to my version of python (i am using 2.7), using bytes gives me int array somehow :(